# Javascript regular expression weird behavior String.match()

Tags: javascript, regex

```
pattern = "p.class1.class2#id1";

regex   =  /#?|\.+/g;
pattern.match(regex) ;

//Outputs ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#", "", "", "", ""]

//Now If I change regex to something like this
regex   =  /#|\.+/g ;
pattern.match(regex);  //Then it gives the correct output 

//Outputs [".", ".", "#"]

//Again If I change regex to something like this
regex   =  /\#|\.*/g;
pattern.match(regex);  //Then it again shows the weird behavior

//Outputs  ["", ".", "", "", "", "", "", "", ".", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#", "", "", "", ""]

//and at last with this regex combination 
regex  =  /\#?|\.*/g;
pattern.match(regex) ; //Its agains outputs something odd

//Outputs ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#", "", "", "", ""];
```

What I need actually to print the correct order of `#` and `.` from a given `pattern` string, where

```
# : Is optional i.e repeat 0 or 1 times
. : Would repeat 0 or more times
```

Since `# and .` could be present in any order in the pattern and all I want Is to print the right order a/c to their occurrence in the string, so can't rely on `()` **capturing groups** in this case.

Some more patterns are:

```
pattern_1 = "p#id.class1.class2"` `//Correct output ['#','.','.']
pattern_2 = ".class1#id.class2"`  `//Correct output ['.','#','.']
pattern_3 = ".class1.class2"`      `//Correct output ['.','.']
```

I am getting this output by using `regex = /#|\.+/g` but don't know what really  happening when i am using these `regex = /#?|\.+/g` **or** `regex = /#?|\.*/g`
Please explain.

Comment: Well empty string is considered as a match. So when you put `#?` and there is no `#` it will try to match 0 times of `#` which returns empty string. No what if you had `#?|\.`, it will try if there is `#`, or `.` or empty string. That's what's happening, most of the times, you don't want empty string, so you just remove `?` and end up using `#|\.`. I got ride from `+` since it means match one or more times the previous token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#?` matches at every position in the string, as empty strings are still considered matches. `.` matches `#?` before it can match `\.` and you end up with a result of empty strings and a hash if there is one.

If you're trying to parse CSS selectors, don't use regex. Just write your own parser.